# SQLite database columns don't get updated with Update method

Tags: android, sqlite

I use SQLite database for my app and i want to save data from multiple activities into one table. in the first activity i use the `add` method to create a row in the table. In the next activity i use `update` method to update the columns in the existing row.
I use *DB Browser for SQLite* app to check my database and it shows datas i saved from second activity are not in database (Null). I don't know what's the problem.
 Here are my classes :
**SQLiteHelper :**

```
    public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements ProjectDAO {

    public SQLiteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "my_db", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE tbl_project_info (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                    "name TEXT," +
                    "company_name TEXT," +
                    "address TEXT," +
                    "length1 TEXT," +
                    "length2 TEXT," +
                    "length3 TEXT," +
                    "length4 TEXT," +
                    "length5 TEXT," +
                    "diameter1 Text,"+
                    "diameter2 Text,"+
                    "diameter3 Text,"+
                    "diameter4 Text,"+
                    "diameter5 Text)");
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            Log.e("SQLITE", "onCreate: " + e.toString());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean addProject(Project project) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("name", project.getName());
        contentValues.put("company_name", project.getCompany_name());
        contentValues.put("address", project.getAddress());
        contentValues.put("length1",project.getLength1());
        contentValues.put("length2",project.getLength2());
        contentValues.put("length3",project.getLength3());
        contentValues.put("length4",project.getLength4());
        contentValues.put("length5",project.getLength5());
        contentValues.put("diameter1",project.getDiameter1());
        contentValues.put("diameter2",project.getDiameter2());
        contentValues.put("diameter3",project.getDiameter3());
        contentValues.put("diameter4",project.getDiameter4());
        contentValues.put("diameter5",project.getDiameter5());
        long result = db.insert("tbl_project_info", null, contentValues);
        db.close();
        return result != -1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getProjectsCount() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_project_info", null);
        int count = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean updateProject(Project project) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("length1",project.getLength1());
        contentValues.put("length2",project.getLength2());
        contentValues.put("length3",project.getLength3());
        contentValues.put("length4",project.getLength4());
        contentValues.put("length5",project.getLength5());
        contentValues.put("diameter1",project.getDiameter1());
        contentValues.put("diameter2",project.getDiameter2());
        contentValues.put("diameter3",project.getDiameter3());
        contentValues.put("diameter4",project.getDiameter4());
        contentValues.put("diameter5",project.getDiameter5());
        db.update("tbl_project_info",contentValues,"id = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(project.getId())});
        db.close();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Project> getAllProjects() {
        List<Project> projects = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_project_info", null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Project project = new Project();
                project.setName(cursor.getString(0));
                project.setCompany_name(cursor.getString(1));
                project.setAddress(cursor.getString(2));
                projects.add(project);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return projects;
    }
}
```

**NewProjectActivity :**

```
public class NewProjectActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ProjectDAO projectDAO;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_project);
        projectDAO = DBInjector.provideProjectDao(this);
        setupViews();
    }

    private void setupViews() {
        final EditText projectNameET = findViewById(R.id.et_newProject_projectName);
        final EditText companyNameET = findViewById(R.id.et_newProject_companyName);
        final EditText addressET = findViewById(R.id.et_newProject_address);
        Button saveInfoBTN = findViewById(R.id.btn_newProject_saveInfo);

        saveInfoBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (projectNameET.length() > 0) {
                    if (companyNameET.length() > 0) {
                        if (addressET.length() > 0) {
                            Project project = new Project();
                            project.setName(projectNameET.getText().toString());
                            project.setCompany_name(companyNameET.getText().toString());
                            project.setAddress(addressET.getText().toString());
                            if (projectDAO.addProject(project)){
                                Toast.makeText(NewProjectActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }else {
                                Toast.makeText(NewProjectActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                Intent intent = new Intent(NewProjectActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

**MainActivity :**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ProjectDAO projectDAO;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        projectDAO = DBInjector.provideProjectDao(this);

        final EditText lengthET1 = findViewById(R.id.et_main_length1);
        final EditText lengthET2 = findViewById(R.id.et_main_length2);
        final EditText lengthET3 = findViewById(R.id.et_main_length3);
        final EditText lengthET4 = findViewById(R.id.et_main_length4);
        final EditText lengthET5 = findViewById(R.id.et_main_length5);
        final EditText diameterET1 = findViewById(R.id.et_main_diameter1);
        final EditText diameterET2 = findViewById(R.id.et_main_diameter2);
        final EditText diameterET3 = findViewById(R.id.et_main_diameter3);
        final EditText diameterET4 = findViewById(R.id.et_main_diameter4);
        final EditText diameterET5 = findViewById(R.id.et_main_diameter5);

        Button calculateButton = findViewById(R.id.btn_main_calculate);
        calculateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                float Le1 = 0;
                if (lengthET1.length() > 0) {
                    String L1 = lengthET1.getText().toString();
                    Le1 = Float.parseFloat(L1);
                }
                float Di1 = 0;
                if (diameterET1.length() > 0) {
                    String D1 = diameterET1.getText().toString();
                    Di1 = Float.parseFloat(D1);
                }
                float Le2 = 0;
                if (lengthET2.length() > 0) {
                    String L2 = lengthET2.getText().toString();
                    Le2 = Float.parseFloat(L2);
                }
                float Di2 = 0;
                if (diameterET2.length() > 0) {
                    String D2 = diameterET2.getText().toString();
                    Di2 = Float.parseFloat(D2);
                }
                float Le3 = 0;
                if (lengthET3.length() > 0) {
                    String L3 = lengthET3.getText().toString();
                    Le3 = Float.parseFloat(L3);
                }
                float Di3 = 0;
                if (diameterET3.length() > 0) {
                    String D3 = diameterET3.getText().toString();
                    Di3 = Float.parseFloat(D3);
                }
                float Le4 = 0;
                if (lengthET4.length() > 0) {
                    String L4 = lengthET4.getText().toString();
                    Le4 = Float.parseFloat(L4);
                }
                float Di4 = 0;
                if (diameterET4.length() > 0) {
                    String D4 = diameterET4.getText().toString();
                    Di4 = Float.parseFloat(D4);
                }
                float Le5 = 0;
                if (lengthET5.length() > 0) {
                    String L5 = lengthET5.getText().toString();
                    Le5 = Float.parseFloat(L5);
                }
                float Di5 = 0;
                if (diameterET5.length() > 0) {
                    String D5 = diameterET5.getText().toString();
                    Di5 = Float.parseFloat(D5);
                }

                final float Surface1 = (float) (Le1 * Di1 * Math.PI);
                final float Surface2 = (float) (Le2 * Di2 * Math.PI);
                final float Surface3 = (float) (Le3 * Di3 * Math.PI);
                final float Surface4 = (float) (Le4 * Di4 * Math.PI);
                final float Surface5 = (float) (Le5 * Di5 * Math.PI);

                final float Surface = Surface1 + Surface2 + Surface3 + Surface4 + Surface5;

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, IntensityActivity.class);
                if (Surface == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No numbers are entered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    intent.putExtra("Result", Surface);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                PersonalInfoSharedPrefManager manager = new PersonalInfoSharedPrefManager(MainActivity.this);
                manager.setSuface(Surface);

                Project project = new Project();

                project.setLength1(lengthET1.getText().toString());
                project.setDiameter1(diameterET1.getText().toString());

                project.setLength2(lengthET2.getText().toString());
                project.setDiameter2(diameterET2.getText().toString());

                project.setLength3(lengthET3.getText().toString());
                project.setDiameter3(diameterET3.getText().toString());

                project.setLength4(lengthET4.getText().toString());
                project.setDiameter4(diameterET4.getText().toString());

                project.setLength5(lengthET5.getText().toString());
                project.setDiameter5(diameterET5.getText().toString());

                projectDAO.updateProject(project);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Your problem when you add new record or when you update exist record?

Comment: @Al-MustafaAzhari When updating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `updateProject` method is roughly saying update values (as per the Contentvalues) where the **project id** is whatever is returned from the project's `getID` method.

However when you create the project to be passed to the method you don't provide the id *(which should be as per the row added in the database)* so it will be some arbitrary value perhaps null (can't say as the Project class isn't included in your code.)

So that's the cause.

There could be a number of fixes. One would be to get the id (very much the preferable/standard method as identifying a row is why you use an id column).

You can retrieve this when adding the project to the database by instead of returning false if the SQLiteDatabase method returns -1 by instead returning the value (the id of the inserted row). You can then check if that is -1 or less than 1 (id will be 1 or greater), which will indicate that the row was not added. If the value is 1 or greater, then the row has been inserted.

You could then pass the id via an IntentExtra to the MainActivity where you would extract and set the projects id to the value. Note you should ideally use **long** for the id as it can be up to a 64 bit signed Integer (Normally it is 1 then 2 then 3 etc.......).

*Another way would be to identify the project from the database according to other know stored values that can uniquely identify the project and then alter the WHERE clause of the `updateProject` method (the 3rd and 4th parameters).*

*Another way would be to extract the id using the identifying information (so a permutation of the above)*

### Suggested fix

- Note this is in-principle code, it has not been tested so may contain some errors:-
- Comments have been include to identify the changes. they will typically be `//<<<<` followed some indication of that has been done.

#### 1) Amend the `addProject` method to return the id else -1 :-

```
@Override
public long addProject(Project project) { //<<<< CHANGED
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("name", project.getName());
    contentValues.put("company_name", project.getCompany_name());
    contentValues.put("address", project.getAddress());
    contentValues.put("length1",project.getLength1());
    contentValues.put("length2",project.getLength2());
    contentValues.put("length3",project.getLength3());
    contentValues.put("length4",project.getLength4());
    contentValues.put("length5",project.getLength5());
    contentValues.put("diameter1",project.getDiameter1());
    contentValues.put("diameter2",project.getDiameter2());
    contentValues.put("diameter3",project.getDiameter3());
    contentValues.put("diameter4",project.getDiameter4());
    contentValues.put("diameter5",project.getDiameter5());
    long result = db.insert("tbl_project_info", null, contentValues);
    db.close();
    return result; //<<<< CHANGED
}
```

#### 2) Pass the id from the NewProjectActivity for the MainActivity :-

```
    saveInfoBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            long projectid = -1; //<<<< LINE ADDED
            if (projectNameET.length() > 0) {
                if (companyNameET.length() > 0) {
                    if (addressET.length() > 0) {
                        Project project = new Project();
                        project.setName(projectNameET.getText().toString());
                        project.setCompany_name(companyNameET.getText().toString());
                        project.setAddress(addressET.getText().toString());
                        projectid = projectDAO.addProject(project); //<<<< LINE ADDED
                        if (projectid > 0){ //<<<< LINE CHANGED
                            Toast.makeText(NewProjectActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else {
                            Toast.makeText(NewProjectActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(NewProjectActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("IE_PROJECTID",projectid); //<<<< ADDED
            startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

#### 3) Retrieve the id in the MainActivity :-

```
private long mProjectID;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    projectDAO = DBInjector.provideProjectDao(this);
    //<<<< ADDED folowing lines to get the id from the intent >>>>
    mProjectID = getIntent().getLongExtra(
                "IE_PROJECTID",
                0 //<<<< NOTE default could be -1 (or any negative) as long as it's less than 1
        );
    .........
                    project.setID(mProjectID); //<<<< ADDED might need setter in project
                    projectDAO.updateProject(project);
```

- use of "IE_PROJECTID" could be replaced with constant, there are some stock ones that can be utilised like `Intent.EXTRA_?????????` *(where ????????? represents many values)*

Comment: Thanks a lot. **it worked!**  
I wanted to save more datas from other activities so created more columns. but surprisingly the new columns didn't get updated and stayed _Null_ ! What i did was passing the id from MainActivity to the next activity just like what i did with the current activities. I don't know what's wrong...

Comment: At a guess the issue with new columns is that the they won't be applied as the onCreate method of the database helper only runs when the database is created. Generally when developing an App the simplest solution is to delete the App's data or uninstall the App and to then rerun the App.

Comment: I somehow do the same. I delete the app database folder using the device file explorer in Android Studio every time i make a change so i'm sure onCreate is called. besides i check the database with _DB Browser for SQLite_ and the columns are there. but they are Null.

Comment: @Hamed I'd suggest adding a new question as the code will be different. I won't be looking at it immediately as I have to go out shortly.

Comment: I asked my new question and haven't found an answer yet. just wanted to give you the link to my new question to have a look. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49629440/sqlite-database-columns-stay-null-on-update-method-in-different-activities)

Answer (score 3):

In **MainActivity** you should set your project id for update:

```
 Project project = new Project();
 project.setId(yourIdValue);
```

Comment: Why should i use `setId` ?   
I mean how do i know what is the id?

Comment: @Hamed You can return id value when you insert project in **NewProjectActivity** . Then put id in **MainActivity** intent.