# SQLite database columns stay Null on update method in different activities

Tags: android, sqlite

I use SQLite database to save data from different activities in my app. in the first activity I use the `add` method to create a row in the table and the next activities use `update` method to update the created columns. my previous question which is somehow similar can be found here :
 [Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49596441/sqlite-database-columns-dont-get-updated-with-update-method)

Previously my problem was with not using `setId`. Now my problem is with the third activity. after calling the `update` method, the columns stay *Null*. I tried passing the id from NewProjectActivity to the MainActivity and then to the IntensityActivity but I don't know why the columns don't get updated. Here are the codes :

**SQLite Helper:**

```
public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements ProjectDAO {

    public SQLiteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "my_db", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE tbl_project_info (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                    "name TEXT," +
                    "company_name TEXT," +
                    "address TEXT," +
                    "length1 TEXT," +
                    "length2 TEXT," +
                    "length3 TEXT," +
                    "length4 TEXT," +
                    "length5 TEXT," +
                    "diameter1 Text," +
                    "diameter2 Text," +
                    "diameter3 Text," +
                    "diameter4 Text," +
                    "diameter5 Text," +
                    "surface Text," +
                    "soilResistance Text," +
                    "intensity Text," +
                    "allowedIntensity Text," +
                    "intensityResult Text)");
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            Log.e("SQLITE", "onCreate: " + e.toString());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    @Override
    public long addProject(Project project) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("name", project.getName());
        contentValues.put("company_name", project.getCompany_name());
        contentValues.put("address", project.getAddress());
        contentValues.put("length1", project.getLength1());
        contentValues.put("length2", project.getLength2());
        contentValues.put("length3", project.getLength3());
        contentValues.put("length4", project.getLength4());
        contentValues.put("length5", project.getLength5());
        contentValues.put("diameter1", project.getDiameter1());
        contentValues.put("diameter2", project.getDiameter2());
        contentValues.put("diameter3", project.getDiameter3());
        contentValues.put("diameter4", project.getDiameter4());
        contentValues.put("diameter5", project.getDiameter5());
        contentValues.put("surface", project.getSurface());
        contentValues.put("soilResistance", project.getSoilResistance());
        contentValues.put("intensity", project.getIntensity());
        contentValues.put("allowedIntensity", project.getAllowedIntensity());
        contentValues.put("intensityResult", project.getIonS());
        long result = db.insert("tbl_project_info", null, contentValues);
        db.close();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public int getProjectsCount() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_project_info", null);
        int count = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean updateProject(Project project) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("length1", project.getLength1());
        contentValues.put("length2", project.getLength2());
        contentValues.put("length3", project.getLength3());
        contentValues.put("length4", project.getLength4());
        contentValues.put("length5", project.getLength5());
        contentValues.put("diameter1", project.getDiameter1());
        contentValues.put("diameter2", project.getDiameter2());
        contentValues.put("diameter3", project.getDiameter3());
        contentValues.put("diameter4", project.getDiameter4());
        contentValues.put("diameter5", project.getDiameter5());
        contentValues.put("surface", project.getSurface());
        contentValues.put("soilResistance", project.getSoilResistance());
        contentValues.put("intensity", project.getIntensity());
        contentValues.put("allowedIntensity", project.getAllowedIntensity());
        contentValues.put("intensityResult", project.getIonS());
        db.update("tbl_project_info", contentValues, "id = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(project.getId())});
        db.close();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Project> getAllProjects() {
        List<Project> projects = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_project_info", null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Project project = new Project();
                project.setName(cursor.getString(0));
                project.setCompany_name(cursor.getString(1));
                project.setAddress(cursor.getString(2));
                projects.add(project);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return projects;
    }
}
```

**NewProjectActivity :**

```
public class NewProjectActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ProjectDAO projectDAO;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_project);
        projectDAO = DBInjector.provideProjectDao(this);
        setupViews();
    }

    private void setupViews() {
        final EditText projectNameET = findViewById(R.id.et_newProject_projectName);
        final EditText companyNameET = findViewById(R.id.et_newProject_companyName);
        final EditText addressET = findViewById(R.id.et_newProject_address);
        Button saveInfoBTN = findViewById(R.id.btn_newProject_saveInfo);

        saveInfoBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                long projectID = -1;
                if (projectNameET.length() > 0) {
                    if (companyNameET.length() > 0) {
                        if (addressET.length() > 0) {
                            Project project = new Project();
                            project.setName(projectNameET.getText().toString());
                            project.setCompany_name(companyNameET.getText().toString());
                            project.setAddress(addressET.getText().toString());
                            projectID = projectDAO.addProject(project);
                            if (projectID > 0){
                                Toast.makeText(NewProjectActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }else {
                                Toast.makeText(NewProjectActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                        }
                        }else {
                        companyNameET.setError("company name not entered");
                    }

                    }else{
                    projectNameET.setError("project name not entered");
                }

                PersonalInfoSharedPrefManager manager = new PersonalInfoSharedPrefManager(NewProjectActivity.this);
                manager.setID(projectID);


                Intent intent = new Intent(NewProjectActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("IE_PROJECTID",projectID);
                startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

**MainActivity :**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ProjectDAO projectDAO;
    private long mProjectID;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        projectDAO = DBInjector.provideProjectDao(this);
        mProjectID = getIntent().getLongExtra("IE_PROJECTID",0);

        final EditText lengthET1 = findViewById(R.id.et_main_length1);
        final EditText lengthET2 = findViewById(R.id.et_main_length2);
        final EditText lengthET3 = findViewById(R.id.et_main_length3);
        final EditText lengthET4 = findViewById(R.id.et_main_length4);
        final EditText lengthET5 = findViewById(R.id.et_main_length5);
        final EditText diameterET1 = findViewById(R.id.et_main_diameter1);
        final EditText diameterET2 = findViewById(R.id.et_main_diameter2);
        final EditText diameterET3 = findViewById(R.id.et_main_diameter3);
        final EditText diameterET4 = findViewById(R.id.et_main_diameter4);
        final EditText diameterET5 = findViewById(R.id.et_main_diameter5);

        Button calculateButton = findViewById(R.id.btn_main_calculate);
        calculateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                float Le1 = 0;
                if (lengthET1.length() > 0) {
                    String L1 = lengthET1.getText().toString();
                    Le1 = Float.parseFloat(L1);
                }
                float Di1 = 0;
                if (diameterET1.length() > 0) {
                    String D1 = diameterET1.getText().toString();
                    Di1 = Float.parseFloat(D1);
                }
                float Le2 = 0;
                if (lengthET2.length() > 0) {
                    String L2 = lengthET2.getText().toString();
                    Le2 = Float.parseFloat(L2);
                }
                float Di2 = 0;
                if (diameterET2.length() > 0) {
                    String D2 = diameterET2.getText().toString();
                    Di2 = Float.parseFloat(D2);
                }
                float Le3 = 0;
                if (lengthET3.length() > 0) {
                    String L3 = lengthET3.getText().toString();
                    Le3 = Float.parseFloat(L3);
                }
                float Di3 = 0;
                if (diameterET3.length() > 0) {
                    String D3 = diameterET3.getText().toString();
                    Di3 = Float.parseFloat(D3);
                }
                float Le4 = 0;
                if (lengthET4.length() > 0) {
                    String L4 = lengthET4.getText().toString();
                    Le4 = Float.parseFloat(L4);
                }
                float Di4 = 0;
                if (diameterET4.length() > 0) {
                    String D4 = diameterET4.getText().toString();
                    Di4 = Float.parseFloat(D4);
                }
                float Le5 = 0;
                if (lengthET5.length() > 0) {
                    String L5 = lengthET5.getText().toString();
                    Le5 = Float.parseFloat(L5);
                }
                float Di5 = 0;
                if (diameterET5.length() > 0) {
                    String D5 = diameterET5.getText().toString();
                    Di5 = Float.parseFloat(D5);
                }

                final float Surface1 = (float) (Le1 * Di1 * Math.PI);
                final float Surface2 = (float) (Le2 * Di2 * Math.PI);
                final float Surface3 = (float) (Le3 * Di3 * Math.PI);
                final float Surface4 = (float) (Le4 * Di4 * Math.PI);
                final float Surface5 = (float) (Le5 * Di5 * Math.PI);

                final float Surface = Surface1 + Surface2 + Surface3 + Surface4 + Surface5;
                long projectID = -1;

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, IntensityActivity.class);
                if (Surface == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No numbers are entered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    intent.putExtra("Result", Surface);
                    intent.putExtra("IE_PROJECTID",projectID);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                PersonalInfoSharedPrefManager manager = new PersonalInfoSharedPrefManager(MainActivity.this);
                manager.setSuface(Surface);


                Project project = new Project();
                project.setId(mProjectID);

                project.setLength1(lengthET1.getText().toString());
                project.setDiameter1(diameterET1.getText().toString());

                project.setLength2(lengthET2.getText().toString());
                project.setDiameter2(diameterET2.getText().toString());

                project.setLength3(lengthET3.getText().toString());
                project.setDiameter3(diameterET3.getText().toString());

                project.setLength4(lengthET4.getText().toString());
                project.setDiameter4(diameterET4.getText().toString());

                project.setLength5(lengthET5.getText().toString());
                project.setDiameter5(diameterET5.getText().toString());

                project.setSurface(String.valueOf(Surface));

                projectDAO.updateProject(project);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**IntensityActivity :**

```
public class IntensityActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ProjectDAO projectDAO;
    private long mProjectID;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_intensity);
        projectDAO = DBInjector.provideProjectDao(this);
        mProjectID = getIntent().getLongExtra("IE_PROJECTID",0);

        final float Result = getIntent().getFloatExtra("Result",0);

        final Button resistanceBTN1 = findViewById(R.id.btn_intensity_R1); 
        final Button resistanceBTN2 = findViewById(R.id.btn_intensity_R2);
        final Button resistanceBTN3 = findViewById(R.id.btn_intensity_R3); 
        final Button resistanceBTN4 = findViewById(R.id.btn_intensity_R4); 
        final Button resistanceBTN5 = findViewById(R.id.btn_intensity_R5);
        final View RL = findViewById(R.id.rl_intensity_allowedIntensity);
        final TextView allowedResistance = findViewById(R.id.tv_intensity_allowedIntensityNumber);
        final TextView surfaceNumber = findViewById(R.id.tv_intensity_surfaceNumber);
        final EditText intensityNumber = findViewById(R.id.et_intensity_intensityNumber); 
        Button calculateButton = findViewById(R.id.btn_intensity_calculate); 
        final Button goToVoltageButton = findViewById(R.id.btn_intensity_goToVoltage);
        final TextView formulaResultNumber = findViewById(R.id.tv_intensity_resultNumber);
        String Sur = Float.toString(Result);
        surfaceNumber.setText(Sur);

        final double R1 = Result*0.250;
        final double R2 = Result*0.125;
        final double R3 = Result*0.050;
        final double R4 = Result*0.025;
        final double R5 = Result*0.010;
        final String Re1 = Double.toString(R1);
        final String Re2 = Double.toString(R2);
        final String Re3 = Double.toString(R3);
        final String Re4 = Double.toString(R4);
        final String Re5 = Double.toString(R5);

        resistanceBTN1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RL.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                allowedResistance.setText(Re1);
            }
        });
        resistanceBTN2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RL.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                allowedResistance.setText(Re2);
            }
        });
        resistanceBTN3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RL.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                allowedResistance.setText(Re3);
            }
        });
        resistanceBTN4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RL.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                allowedResistance.setText(Re4);
            }
        });
        resistanceBTN5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RL.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                allowedResistance.setText(Re5);
            }
        });

        calculateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String I = intensityNumber.getText().toString();
                float In = Float.parseFloat(I);
                float R = In/Result;
                String Res = String.valueOf(R);
                formulaResultNumber.setText(Res);
                goToVoltageButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                PersonalInfoSharedPrefManager manager = new PersonalInfoSharedPrefManager(IntensityActivity.this);
                manager.setIntensity(In);


            }
        });

        goToVoltageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(IntensityActivity.this,SimpleVoltage.class);
                startActivity(intent);

                Project project = new Project();
                project.setId(mProjectID);

                project.setAllowedIntensity(String.valueOf(allowedResistance));
                project.setIntensity(intensityNumber.getText().toString());

                projectDAO.updateProject(project);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From `MainActivity` to `IntensityActivity`, What I found is that you are always passing -1 in Project ID

```
final float Surface = Surface1 + Surface2 + Surface3 + Surface4 + Surface5;
                long projectID = -1;

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, IntensityActivity.class);
                if (Surface == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No numbers are entered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    intent.putExtra("Result", Surface);
                    intent.putExtra("IE_PROJECTID",projectID);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
```

Instead you can pass the same ID you have got on this activity from Intent

Just update your code in `MainActivity` as below and pass `mProjectID`.

```
 final float Surface = Surface1 + Surface2 + Surface3 + Surface4 + Surface5;
                long projectID = -1;

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, IntensityActivity.class);
                if (Surface == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No numbers are entered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    intent.putExtra("Result", Surface);
                    intent.putExtra("IE_PROJECTID",mProjectID);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Now the entries from MainActivity don't get saved and it shows they are _Null_! but IntensityActivity data gets saved!

Comment: The above ans does not relate to the MainActivity data saving. I just noticed that the project id you are passing to next activity is wrong and changed that only. The problem with MainActivity saving data is probably a different one.

Comment: Yeah i know. but that's what happend when i changed the `intent.putExtra` line! it's strange but that's the only line i changed.

Comment: Just below the Code you are starting IntensityActivity from MainActivity, There is a Code to update the Project. That has caused some issue. Just try to comment it out and check.

Comment: What i'm trying to do is to update the Project! if i comment out that part of my code which is responsible for updating the database, then what is left to solve? it's already not being updated.

Comment: You can just comment to check and trace that there is something going wrong in updating the database in that method. so that you can resolve it. Comment it for just test purpose.

Answer (score 0):

try this way in your update method,

```
 db.update("tbl_project_info", contentValues, "id="+String.valueOf(project.getId()), null);
```

Also you need to change following line into MainActivity.java

```
long projectID = -1;
```

to

```
long projectID = mProjectID;
```

Comment: tried it. didn't work. do i have to change something else or just this line should do it?

Comment: replace your db.update line with mine . it must work. I ran into same problem.

Comment: @Hamed, is it possible for you to send code via email ?

Comment: Yeah sure. give me your email address

Comment: @Hamed, yes please send it on same email.